# What are you allowed to move into the big O notation for it to be still correct?

Tags: big-o-notation

Can someone tell me what the rules are for moving log or exponents into the $O(n)$ notation so it is still correct?

For example: Is this $\log(O(n))= O(\log(n))$ correct? Or is this correct $O(n)^2=O(n^2)$? Or am I not allowed to do this?

Comment: Also, as you may already realize, being in Computer Science, "equality" is not symmetrical, especially with regard to big-O notation, as in $f(x)=O(g(x))$, because it's really/more precisely $f(x)\in O(g(x))$... So some versions of this question (and of answers) can be inadvertently garbled by at some moments accidentally treating equality with regard to big-O stuff as if it were symmetric. It _can_ be, if we realize that $O(f(x))$ is a _set_, not a single thing, etc.

Comment: @paulgarrett: It is **not** symmetric even if you treat it as a set....... $O(n^2) ≠ O(n)$.

Comment: @user21820, right, sets can be equal, but also only contained, etc., so to write $O(n)\subseteq O(n^2)$ makes sense and is correct.

Comment: @paulgarrett: Absolutely, that's why I use "⊆" where appropriate, and never "=" if it is not truly equal.

Comment: @user21820: I would tend to assume that you can fix this by switching to big theta notation, but I'm not sure if big theta *actually* forms well-behaved equivalence classes. Intuitively, it seems like it should, however.

Comment: Just curious, did log(O(n)) come up in a real problem? If so, how? I'm trying to imagine a function that runs in O(n), then you're somehow taking the log of ... that function? Is log(O(n)) even well-defined?

Comment: @OwenReynolds: Perhaps some algorithm involves storing elements in a balanced binary tree, where the number of elements it needs to store is at most proportional to the size of the input, and the height of the tree is equal to the log of the number of elements it contains. Then the height of the tree is in $\{ \log(f(n)) : f(n) \in O(n) \}$ -- or $\log(O(n))$ for short.

Comment: @Kevin: How is Θ relevant? You can't use merely Θ to say "3n·log(n) ∈ O(n^2) as n → ∞", no matter what you do.

Comment: @ruakh But wouldn't you leave f(n) as merely f(n), giving log(f(n)) and then apply O at the end? I suppose if f(n) had some complex, fragile analysis? This seems like an XY problem.

Comment: @user21820: The point is that you don't (shouldn't) say that in the first place. Instead, you say 3n log n = Θ(n log n), and then you can treat Θ(n log n) *exactly* like any other function, without having to worry about whether = is symmetric.

Comment: @Kevin: The point is that if you do that then the asymptotic notation becomes nearly useless! At some point you **have** to use some non-symmetric relation between asymptotic classes, in order to get useful results.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To prove or disprove this kind of equality with $\mathcal{O}$, you need to go back to the definition of $\mathcal{O}$ with inequalities.

For example, let's study the question $\log(\mathcal{O}(n)) = \mathcal{O}(\log n)$:

$f\in \log(\mathcal{O}(n))$ means that there exists a function $g\in\mathcal{O}(n)$ so that $f = \log g$. That means there exists a constant $A>0$ such that:

$$f(n) = \log g(n) \leqslant \log (An) = \log A + \log n\leqslant 2\log n$$

The first inequality holds true because $\log$ is an increasing function. The second inequality holds true for $n$ big enough. We proved that $f \in \mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Reciprocally, $f\in \mathcal{O}(\log n)$ means that there exists $B>0$ such that $f(n) \leqslant B\log n$. That means:
$$2^{f(n)}\leqslant 2^{B\log n} = n^B$$
Therefore, we cannot conclude that $2^f\in \mathcal{O}(n)$, or equivalently that $f\in \log(\mathcal{O}(n))$.

For example, consider $f(n) = 2\log n$. Then clearly, $f\in \mathcal{O}(\log n)$, but $2^{f(n)} = n^2 \notin \mathcal{O}(n)$.

In the general case, we have:

- $\log(\mathcal{O}(n))\subsetneq \mathcal{O}(\log n)$;
- $(\mathcal{O}(n))^k = \mathcal{O}(n^k)$;
- $\mathcal{O}(2^n) \subsetneq 2^{\mathcal{O}(n)}$.

Comment: But is log(O(n^k))=O(log(n)) ok?

Comment: No, because if $f(n) = (k+1)\log n$, then $f\in \mathcal{O}(\log n)$, but $2^{f(n)} = n^{k+1}$, so $f\notin \log(\mathcal{O}(n^k))$.

Comment: However, I think $\bigcup\limits_{k\geqslant 0}\log(\mathcal{O}(n^k)) = \mathcal{O}(\log n)$.

Comment: $g(n)=e^{-n}$ is $\mathcal O(n)$, but $\log g(n)=-n$ is not $\mathcal O(\log n)$

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen That's right, I was implicitly considering positive functions.

Answer (score 8):

In order for $f(O(n)) \in O(f(n))$ to hold you essentially want $f$ to satisfy $f(cn) \le df(n)$ where $n$ is sufficiently large. Here the inequality must hold for all sufficiently large constants $c$, while $d$ is a constant that can be chosen as a function of $c$ (but not as a function of  $n$).

For example $\log cn \le \log c + \log n \le (1+ \log c) \log n$ for $n \ge 2$ and $c \ge 1$, so you can pick $d=(1+ \log c)$.

Also: $(cn)^2 = c^2 n^2$ for any $c \ge 0$ so you can pick $d=c^2$.

Notice that you can't just move any function into the Big-Oh notation. For example $2^{O(n)} \not\in O(2^n)$.
Indeed, when $c > 1$, you can always satisfy $2^{cn} > d 2^n$ for any $d$ chosen independently of $n$, by simply considering values of $n$ that are large enough.

Comment: I think that $2^{O(n)}$ is not equal to $O(2^n)$. For example, $2^{2n}$ is clearly in $2^{O(n)}$, but since it is equal to $4^n$, it is not in $O(2^n)$.

Comment: @Nathaniel. Yep, you are right. That's exactly what that sentence was trying to point out but I realize that it was really confusing. I rephrased the last paragraph, it should read better now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although $\mathcal O(f(n))$ will often be given as a function, e.g. $\mathcal n^2+n=\mathcal O(n^2)$, strictly speaking $\mathcal O(f(n))$ is a set of functions, so the precise statement is  $n^2+n \in \mathcal O(n^2)$. The expressions $\mathcal \log(O(f(n))$  and $\mathcal O(f(n))^2$ don't really make sense. You can't do math on $\mathcal O(f(n))$, other than set operations.

Comment: What you say is formally correct but writing, e.g., $f(n) = 2^{O(n)}$ is a commonly accepted abuse of notation to mean that there exists some function $g(n) \in O(n)$ such that $f(n) = 2^{g(n)}$. Then $\log O(f(n))$ would be the set $\{ \log g(n) \mid g(n) \in O(f(n)) \}$ and $O(f(n))^2$ would be the set $\{ (g(n))^2 \mid g(n) \in O(f(n)) \}$.

Comment: @Steven If I were to see $O(f(n))^2$ I would immediately think $O(f(n))\times O(f(n))$, putting it next to other abuses of notation helps imply the intended meaning, but I definitely don't think it's a good idea for the sake of the reader to extend this abuse of notation arbitrarily.