# Does $f(n) \in O(g(n))$ imply $2^{f(n)} \in O(2^{g(n)})$?

Tags: big-o-notation

Is the following true: $$  f(n) \in O(g(n)) \text{ then } 2 ^ {f(n)} \in O(2^{g(n)})$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are you allowed to move into the big O notation for it to be still correct?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/145977/what-are-you-allowed-to-move-into-the-big-o-notation-for-it-to-be-still-correct)

Comment: Hint: consider $f(n)=2 \log n$ and $g(n)=\log n$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An obvious counterexample is $f(n) = n$ and $g(n) = \frac{n}{2}$. We know that $f(n) \in O(g(n))$, but $2^{f(n)} = 2^n \not \in O(2^{g(n)}) = O(2^{\frac{n}{2}}) = O(\sqrt{2^n})$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you would ask: For a function h(n), if f(n) = O(g(n)), is h(f(n)) = O(h(g(n))?

We have f(n) < c * g(n) for some constant c, and for large n. The function h(n) must be such that within the range of f(n) and g(n), h(f(n)) must not grow so fast that a linear change in f(n) creates a non-linear change in h(f(n)).